# Commit pushed with 2 authors

Tags: git

I have my work ssh keys set on my local system. Now I also, tried to push a project to my personal github account.

I changed the author of the commit while committing.
On `git log` I can see the new author.

```
commit 73344e555da22600723a8302b7d476787f2668e3 (HEAD -> master)
Author: A G <laun.biz@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed May 29 00:35:41 2019 +0530

    First Commit
```

I pushed it using username and password.

```
git push https://username:password@github.com/Laun/laun-api.git master
```

Now when I go and check on Github , I see,

```
Laun and agupta-at-wellthie First Commit
```

`Laun` is my personal username and
`agupta-at-wellthie` is my work account username. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

> I changed the author of the commit while committing.

That's fine—but you didn't change the *committer*.

Every commit has not one but *two* "who made this commit, and when" stamps on it: the *author*, which you can override with `--author` in `git commit`, and the *committer*, which has no obvious command-line option to override it.

It's possible to override all six parts individually, through six environment variables:

- `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` sets the name part of the author line
- `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` sets the email-address part of the author line
- `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` sets the date-and-time-stamp part of the author line
- `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` sets the name part of the committer line
- `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` sets the email address part of the committer line
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` sets the date-and-time-stamp part of the committer line

If you *don't* override individual parts with environment variables, they default to:

- author: you, or from `--author`, or from the author in a commit you referenced with `-c` or `-C`.
- committer: you.

In this case, "you" means:

- the setting from `user.name`, plus
- the setting from `user.email`, plus
- the current date-and-time as reported by your computer's clock.

Hence one way to override everything in a new commit (one without information copied from some existing commit) is to set your `user.name` and `user.email`, either through `git config` or through the command line:

```
git -c user.name='A U Thor' -c user.email='thor@example.com' commit
```

If you add `--author='Someone Else <else@example.com>'`, the `--author` part here will override the author line, while the committer line will come from the two `-c` parts (and the current time stamp).

If you want to override the committer time stamp, the only mechanism is to use `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, or change your computer's clock (either suffices, and of course the environment variable is easier and safer as it won't disturb the rest of your computer).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't override with command line, so I added [user] name and email in git config file. Too complicated to understand the whole thing, but kind of solves my problem :)